# Deleting multiplie resources by mask using WEB DAV

Tags: webdav

Is there any way to delete multiplie resources by mask with web dav protocol out of a box?

For example send some header with condition like regex, for example

'^some.*' - delete all resources starting with 'some'

Maybe somebody had thinking about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no part of the webdav or http11 standards for that. A DELETE is always issued to a single resource identified by the URL